# When use istanbul, is there any way to dynamic require config.js?

Tags: node.js, testing, istanbul

[image]

The `logEnable` is write in `config.js`, is there any way to change the value during testing? So than I can improve the branch coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ignore parts of code from testing: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md

> Skip an if or else path with `/* istanbul ignore if */` or `/* istanbul ignore else */` respectively.
>
> For all other cases, skip the next 'thing' in the source with: `/* istanbul ignore next */`

Or add a single test that checks just those logging functions with both logging enabled and disabled (you can override required modules, like your config, for example with proxyquire: https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire).